# Why we need rbegin and rend?

Tags: c++

Since we now have `advance()` and the `prev()` to move iterator to go front or go back, and we already have `begin()` and `end()`.

I wonder is there any situation we better/have to move reverse iterator back and front?

Comment: @tadman forward_list doesn't have reverse iterators

Comment: @Caleth Fair enough. Trying to think of a situation where a reverse iterator works better.

Comment: Maybe a corner case: if you want to create a new container, equal to the reverse of an existing one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Algorithms often take two iterators that specify a range of elements. For example `std::for_each`:

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::for_each(x.begin(),x.end(),foo);
```

If you want to make `for_each` iterate in reverse order (note: `for_each` does iterate in order) then neither `advance` nor `prev` are of any help, but you can use reverse iterators:

```
std::for_each(x.rbegin(),x.rend(),foo);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because using `begin()` and `end()` to iterate in reverse looks horrible:

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};
if(!v.empty()) { //need to make sure of that before we decrement
    for(auto it = std::prev(v.end()); ; --it) {
        //do something with it
        if(it == v.begin()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Compare it with reverse iterator version:

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};
for(auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); it++) {
    //do something with it
}
```

Comment: In addition, fist snippet cannot use `continue` (without rechecking `it` versus `v.begin()`).

Answer (score 1):

When you have a function template that takes iterators, and want it to operate on the data in reverse.

E.g.

```
std::string s = "Hello";
std::string r(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
std::cout << r;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use algorithms like `std::for_each()`, `std::accumulate()`, `std::find_if()`... they systematically progress with `++`.
If you want this progression to physically occur backwards, then the reverse
iterators are useful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is good practise because it seems odd if you start from end and finish in begin. You can easily say last but one by using rbegin.

vector::reverse_iterator itr1;

```
for (itr1 = vec.rbegin(); itr1 < vec.rend(); itr1++) { 

    if (*itr1 == num) { 

          vec.erase((itr1 + 1).base()); 
    } 
}
```

You can use as a function which deletes that Which num want to erase in vector

Comment: Yes, but some functions like erase cannot take reverse iterators. So i feel in most case is safer to use regular iterator.

Comment: I think all about is understandable writing and easily thinking

Answer (score 1):

The need for [`rbegin()/rend()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) is because `begin()` is not the same as `rend()`, and `end()` is not `rbegin()`, see this image from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin)

> [image]

This way, you can use any algorithm going forward from beginning to end or backwards from the last to the first element.

Comment: Just FYI: your image has a transparent background which results on black text on dark background if you're wiewing Stackoverflow in the dark theme.

Comment: @rubenvb I changed the background to white, is this working better?

Comment: Right. But you can use prev(example.end()) to reach example.rbegin(). For rend(), probably cannot use prev(example.begin()).

Comment: You can modify any algorithm to go forward or backwards, of course. But typically algorithms don't care about direction, and with `rbegin/rend` there is no need to.

Comment: You might want to explain why they are not the same and why a reverse iterator internally stores an iterator to the next element.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples with for each. However, more general, it allows you to reuse *any* algorithm or operators that works with iterators with advancing, to do the same thing but in a reverse order.