# Why sort(rbegin(), rend()) sort the structure on descending order?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, iterator, reverse-iterator

for example the code bellow sort the vec on desc order :

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 5, 4, 3};
sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend());
for(const auto v : vec)
    std::cout << v << "\n";
output 5 4 3 2 1
```

On the [C++ reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort):

> Sorts the elements in the range [first,last) into ascending order. The elements are compared using operator< for the first version [...]

Comment: That reference is inherently bad in wording, but if you look up, what `rbegin()` and `rend()` actually do, it's clear why `sort()` behaves like this, despite the wording in that "reference".

Comment: This probably should be a question about [what `rbegin` and `rend` mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887066/why-we-need-rbegin-and-rend).  It seems pretty clear that `std::sort` isn't what is confusing the OP.  The code claims to produce "output", but there's no output here without reading the vector in the opposite order.

Comment: sorry yes, for the output I'm using     
for(const auto v : vec)
        std::cout << v << "\n";

Comment: @AwesomeJSF That's a helpful edit.  That for loop uses `begin()` and `end()`.  Which iterate in the opposite order of `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

Answer (score 6):

The function call indeed sorts the vector in the ascending order starting form the last element up to the first element because there are used reverse iterators

```
sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend());
```

When you are using reverse iterators then the vector is traversed in the reverse order.

Consider this for loop

```
for (auto first = vec.rbegin(), last = vec.rend(); first != last; ++first)
{
    std::cout << *first << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Its output is

```
3 4 5 2 1
```

If you want to sort the vector in the ascending order in the direct direction then do not use the reverse iterators. For example

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Or if to use the reverse iterators then instead of the default function object of the type `std::less<int>` you need to use a function object of the type `std::greater<int>`

```
sort( vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), std::greater<int>() );
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `vec.rbegin() + 1` is the 2nd-last element in the array.  Note the _positive_ offset (+1).  That means that the "ascending" order is applied in the order of positive iteration of the iterators.  You could make a custom iterator that walks the array in some other arbitrary order (perhaps interleaved FFT butterfly or any other exotic ordering) to create a path through the items in the array, and `sort` will to put the items in ascending order __along that path__.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you, I don't know how to mark your comment on "accepted answer".